# Rating Bar not changing

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-seekbar

SO the app I am writing has two(so far) seekbars that are in a Fragment. The rating bar is in the Main layout file. What I need to happen is the Rating Bar progress to change based on the values of the SeekBars. Here is the code, so you have a better idea:

**Fragment Java File**

```
package com.example.tipquiz;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuizFragment extends Fragment implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    SeekBar fqBar, cBar;
    TextView fqTV, cTV;
    TextView fqTVP, cTVP;
    RatingBar rb;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quiz_fragment_layout, container,
                false);
        //Inflate the Main layout to access the RatingBar
        View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        //FoodQuality Bar
        fqBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBarFQ);
        fqBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        fqTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewFQ2);
        fqTVP = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewFQP);

        //Cleanliness Bar
        cBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBarC);
        cBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        cTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewC2);
        cTVP = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewCP);

        rb = (RatingBar) mainView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
        return view;


    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        switch(arg0.getId()) {

        case R.id.seekBarFQ:
            if(progress > 70 && progress < 90){
                fqTV.setText("Above Average - ");
                rb.setRating(4);
            }else if(progress > 40 && progress <= 70){
                fqTV.setText("Average - ");
            }else if(progress <= 40){
                fqTV.setText("Awful - ");
            }else if(progress > 90){
                fqTV.setText("Perfect - ");
            }
            fqTVP.setText(progress + "%");
            break;

        case R.id.seekBarC:
            if(progress > 70 && progress < 90){
                cTV.setText("Above Average - ");        
            }else if(progress > 40 && progress <= 70){
                cTV.setText("Average - ");
            }else if(progress <= 40){
                cTV.setText("Awful - ");
            }else if(progress > 90){
                cTV.setText("Perfect - ");
            }
            cTVP.setText(progress + "%");
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**Main Class**

```
package com.example.tipquiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnRatingBarChangeListener{

    // Testing Stuff to show the rating value, will need to use later for maths
    static RatingBar rb;
    TextView tv;

    // The Image used as the DropDown button, Rotate code below
    ImageView dropDownButton;

    Boolean hasRotated = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dropDownButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dropDownButton);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    QuizFragment qf = new QuizFragment();

    public void dropDown(View view){
        if(hasRotated == false){
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
            dropDownButton.setRotation(90);
            ft.add(R.id.quizFragment, qf);
            ft.show(qf);
            ft.commit();
            hasRotated = true;
        }else if(hasRotated == true){
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_out, android.R.animator.fade_out);
            dropDownButton.setRotation(0);
            hasRotated = false;
            ft.remove(qf);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
            boolean fromTouch) {
        // final int numStars = ratingBar.getNumStars();
        tv.setText(rating + "/5.0");
    }
    // http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/08/android-rating-bar-example.html#.U7SZ5fldXm4
}
```

I've tried to do this many ways, and most ways I've gone about doing this give me an error in Eclipse, or a crash. The method I'm using now doesn't crash or give any errors, yet the rating bar doesn't change when it is supposed to.

I've also tried to simply use MainActivity.rb.setProgress(4); in the if statement, but I got this crash:

> D/(938): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7ca38d0, tid 938
>   W/EGL_emulation(938): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   D/OpenGLRenderer(938): Enabling debug mode 0
>    E/InputEventReceiver(938): Exception dispatching input event.
>   Shutting down VM
>    W/dalvikvm(938): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3b0db90)
>    D/dalvikvm(938): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 94K, 6% free 3184K/3360K, paused 31ms, total 37ms
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938): Process: com.example.tipquiz, PID: 938
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938): java.lang.NullPointerException
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at com.example.tipquiz.QuizFragment.onProgressChanged(QuizFragment.java:50)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:91)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:655)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:667)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(ProgressBar.java:714)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.trackTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:451)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:379)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7690)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2066)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2457)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2014)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7870)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3919)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3808)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3456)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3425)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3510)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3433)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3567)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3456)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3425)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3433)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5520)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5500)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5471)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5594)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:174)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5573)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5613)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:530)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>    E/AndroidRuntime(938):     a

Comment: Does the text change when you move the seekbar?

Comment: Yes the text changes fine on both seekbars, and they move independently of one another, which is what I want. However, the crash I posted happens when the Food Quality seekbar enters the 70% text area

Comment: @DtrollMC Which is line 50 in `QuizFragment`?

Comment: Line 50 is where I set the rating.

Comment: Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try put a float value. instead of 4 try put 4f

Comment: Actually i just tested this, and it doesn't matter if it's int or float. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

In **MainActivity**:

```
public static int rating = 0;

private RatingBar rb;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    rb = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
    rb.setRating(rating);
}
```

And in **QuizFragment**:
**REMOVE** this line

`rb = (RatingBar) mainView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);`

then:

```
if (progress > 70 && progress < 90){
    fqTV.setText("Above Average - ");
    MainActivity.rating = 4;
}
```

Comment: Very clever idea, so I tried this, and yet the ratingbar still doesn't change. I've tried the same thing with setProgress

Comment: @DtrollMC try adding this to the RatingBar `android:isIndicator="false"`

Comment: nope that doesn't work either. I should also mention that when the SeekBars are at the 70 mark, they seem to grow a tad larger. Not very relevant but I thought I should share.